API returns reputation history events for deleted posts, yet no post_deleted events are included. Why? Bug? What do I do?
This SE API request for user 30382 of Mathematics site returns the following items:
...
{"reputation_history_type":"post_downvoted","reputation_change":-2,"post_id":4949321,"creation_date":1721723662,"user_id":30382},
{"reputation_history_type":"post_upvoted","reputation_change":10,"post_id":4949321,"creation_date":1721717548,"user_id":30382},
{"reputation_history_type":"post_downvoted","reputation_change":-2,"post_id":4949321,"creation_date":1721716640,"user_id":30382},
{"reputation_history_type":"post_downvoted","reputation_change":-2,"post_id":4949321,"creation_date":1721716308,"user_id":30382},
...

These are all the reputation history events the user has for post 4949321, which has been deleted.
According to this answer, users do not keep reputation for a deleted post, unless the post satisfied both conditions:


has a score of 3 or higher
is deleted 60 days (1440 hours, 86400 minutes) later than its creation timestamp.


This SEDE query shows that the answer was on 0 days and was deleted with Score -2, so it clearly does not satisfy the conditions to keep the reputation. Yet the reputation-history endpoint returns upvotes and downvotes with a net positive. Why?

Update. Thanks to generous insights provided in the comments by @testing-for-ya and @Makyen, my current understanding is as follows.
When a post is deleted, post_downvoted and post_upvoted events are not removed from the rephistory. If a deletion of a post incurs a reputation adjustment, then such an adjustment is made by adding a post_deleted rephistory event. However, all post_deleted events seem to be blanket censored from the public API, because some post_deleted events may be leaking private information, such as +1 downvote refunds (which would unambiguously indicate that a user downvoted the deleted post). Interestingly, public user reputation page does not show reputation due to post_downvoted and post_upvoted, and at the same time it does not show downvote refunds either. If reputation history API endpoint behaved the same way, then it would allow for a more precise reputation estimate.
In the comments, the discussion has naturally evolved from "why I do get events that should be effectively cancelled (post_upvoted)" to "why I do not get events (post_deleted) that signify that other events (post_upvoted) should be effectively cancelled". The focus of the my question might have shifted, but the gist remains the same:

Is there a way to correctly account for reputation of post_downvoted, post_upvoted etc events, which must have been (and indeed was) adjusted due to a deletion of a post?

Also, can I have a confirmation from SE staff if this is a bug or not, and that I am correct as to why all post_deleted events are censored in public reputation-history API?

Comments have been archived in chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments.

Here is a tentative answer to "what do I do" part of my question, opinions are welcome.
In order to tell which reputation history events were effectively undone by a hidden post_deleted event, one should compare data from users/{ids}/reputation-history and users/{ids}/reputation API endpoints. Reputation history events should be aggregated by post, date and possibly type, and then compared to a similar aggregation of reputation events. The posts that do not match most likely have a post_deleted event in reputation history (and have its reputation effect reversed).
This method would be absolutely robust if the following assumptions held:

all reputation-history events are aggregated into reputation events;
post_deleted, voter_downvotes, and voter_undownvotes are always censored from the public reputation history API, and these are the only censored event types;
censored events cannot combine to produce net zero.

These assumptions probably don't hold, but the method will probably work as described or with minor modifications.

Let's compare the method I propose with the way outlined in Makyen's comment:

You will probably need to separately determine which posts of the user's are not deleted (i.e., get their list of posts), potentially from /users/{ids}/posts (or other endpoint). That should tell you which posts of theirs are not deleted. As far as I'm aware, there's no way to determine the timestamp for the deletion from the SE API.

Matching users/{ids}/reputation-history to users/{ids}/reputation takes more API requests and computation. It does not tell us the deletion timestamp either, but we do not need it anymore, because we learn directly if the reputation is kept.
If the API calls and computation becomes a bottle neck, then we could combine the two methods: use /users/{ids}/posts or /posts/{ids}/ to learn which posts are still extant. For the remaining posts mentioned in reputation-history (if any), check whether they left a trace in reputation. No need to scan reputation completely, can use fromdate=. If no trace of a post is found in reputation API, then it has been deleted with reputation adjusted. Otherwise, the post may still be deleted, but the reputation was kept.
